# KQL/Kusto - how to get String between conditions

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I wanted to get the strings inside the ( ) parenthesis but im not sure what KQL function to do it.

```
123 (SuperLongText) - Repeatative Suffix
12345 (SuperLongText) - Repeatative Suffix
3213 (ShortText) - Repeatative Suffix
```

Answer (score 3):

[`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) is probably what you want to use here:

```
| parse InputText with * "(" superLongText ") -" * 
| project InputText, superLongText
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something below

```
substring("123 (SuperLongText)"
    , indexof("123 (SuperLongText)","(")
    , indexof("123 (SuperLongText)",")") - indexof("123 (SuperLongText)","(")
    )
```